# how can i magento remove v:Breadcrumb - format error

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

For some reason, breadcrumbs is formatted all wrong - arrows over text and the start of breadcrumbs is way over to the left and not in-line with the template

**Problem Code:**

```
<ul>
<li class="home">
<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
<a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="Go to Home Page" href="your-url/">Home</a>
&nbsp; »
</span>
</li>
<li class="category96">
<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
<a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="" href="your-url">Accessories</a>
&nbsp; »
</span>
</li>
<li class="category6">
<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
<strong>Scope</strong>
</span>
</li>
```

**Using Firebug i found that if i make these changes, then it is displayed exactly as i required:**

```
<ul>
<li class="home">
<a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="Go to Home Page" href="your-     url/">Home</a>
&nbsp; »
</li>
<li class="category96">
<a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="" href="your-url">Accessories</a>
&nbsp; »
</span>
</li>
<li class="category6">
<strong>Scope</strong>
</li>
```

PROBLEM
Where do i make these changes in the file structure of magento?

could be a school boy error but has been driving me mad all day

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Breadcrumb content are rendered from the following file

```
 app\design\frontend\<your_package>\<your_theme>\template\page\html\ breadcrumbs.phtml
```

If the file is not present in your theme. Get the copy of the file from base/default or rwd/default theme.

Then paste it in your theme with above file path.

Comment: Hi thanks, it seems it was actually an issue in /httpdocs/app/etc/modules/Magmodules_Snippets.xml all solved